# Define function with more than 1 prototype

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, overloading

I am working on a function that I would like to define more than one prototype and was wondering if this is possible.

I know visual studios does this for some of their function calls but wasn't sure if it was something that was possible to do on my own.

Comment: Could you give a code example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Addition to the answers below: default parameter value is a .NET 3.5 C# feature. I see you are using VS2010. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602234/c-sharp-default-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) a function:

```
public void Function() {

}

public void Function(string argument) {

}

public void Function(string argument, string argument) {

}
```

Or you can use [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
public void Function(params string[] arguments) {

}
```

You can then invoke the function via:

```
 Function("argument1", "argument2", "argument3");
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I wanted to know, Thanks. As soon as it lets me, I'll select this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Darren wrote, you can create overloads in C#

With the introduction of optional parameters and default values, some of these can be reduced to a single implementation:

For instance,

```
 public void Foo(string param1, int param2)
 {
   ...
 }

 public void Foo(string param1)
 {
   Foo(param1, 12);
 }
```

Can be replaced by

```
 public void Foo(string param1, int param2 = 12)
 {
   ...
 }
```